# Launch Windows Explorer from Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, html, windows, internet-explorer

Is it possible to launch Windows Explorer to show a specific folder by clicking on a link on my page?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

No, I'm afraid it's not possible to do so in exactly the way you describe. If you want to emulate that sort of functionality you'd need to buy/build an ActiveX control to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using the [File URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

But there's no real way to guarantee your client has the directory on their machine. Or that their browser will support the scheme (Firefox and Chrome do not support this).

Comment: It's not possible in modern browsers. I believe that will work, but only in IE7 and below.

Comment: works for me in IE8, but you're right. Firefox and Chrome do not support it.

Comment: it will work for any browser if you tested it by creating the page and running it on your local machine. The problem comes when you try access it through HTTP.

Comment: I know, I currently use it to hit a network share from our internal wiki (i.e. very controlled environment).  The OP did not specify whether or not the website would be public facing.